# Using JPA in java from an EntityFramework in .Net perspective

Tags: java, .net, entity-framework, jsf, jpa

I am very familiar with the .net framework. but new to java technologies. I am working on data-driven web application (using Netbeans, MySql, Glassfish) for my course work.

I have spent weeks trying to figure out how to use JPA technology for my JSF interface based web application. My assumption is that it is similar to entity framework in .net. I have searched and searched but it seems the videos/tutorials/explanations are for java people only.

**If there is anyone who has transitioned from .net to java succesfully or who understands both platforms to help me.**

I have created the entity classes so far, so I want to know what to do to be able to -

**-Get and manage instance of entities from database,**

**-Manipulate and navigate through the entities**

**-Then save changes back to the database.**

(just like in .net using the context.*entityname*.add(*new entityInstance*) and context.SubmitChanges() method to save changes back to the database.)

so how can I set the entity manager up and get it to work assuming I want to use it in a Managed Bean class backing my JSF pages.**

If I try to follow the documentation or tutorials from a java only based developer. I find it very difficult to understand.

A link to an article from a .net perspective can also be helpful.

Thanx alot.

Comment: Try visting this hope this help: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/jsf-jpa-tutorial-095959.html